# User type Login system Yii 2.0

Tags: php, yii2

I have a problem on getting a property from model User . Simply the code should get the type of user whether its admin or normal user then each of them redirect to their controllers . 
code at controller :

```
public function actionIndex()
    {

     if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
           return $this->render('index');
        } else {
            // Administrator
            if (Yii::$app->session->get('user.type') == 1) {
              return  $this->redirect('admin');
                //user
             Yii::$app->session->get('user.type') == 2) {
                return $this->redirect('normal-user');
                }
             else {
                  Yii::$app->user->logout();
                        return $this->refresh();
            }
        }
}
```

This type is from My database table and it only have two values "1" or "2" . when i check this its getting "0" don't know how .so it always logout() any suggestions might be not taken on my consideration !!!

Comment: Are you registering the user.type in the session after you login the user?

Comment: why should i do this i wanna get it from the database table

Comment: Ok thank you the problem solved using this instead:Yii::$app->user->identity->type

Comment: You are better of keeping that part in the session. You can of course do that but I believe it will request from the DB the value every time

Comment: you should overwrite the identity class with your own and keep things in the session with it.

Comment: see this as an example https://github.com/Mihai-P/yii2-core/blob/master/components/User.php